# Determinant and tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant

Let $V$ be a complex vector space of dimension $n$ with basis $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$. Further $$\text{Alt}^n(V)=\left\{\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)v_1\otimes ...\otimes v_n : v_i\in V\right\}\subset V^{\otimes n}.$$

If we define $b:=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)e_1\otimes ...\otimes e_n$, then $\{b\}$ is a basis of $\text{Alt}^n(V)$.

Now define a linear map as follows: $$f:\text{Alt}^n(V)\rightarrow\mathbb{C},\quad b\mapsto 1.$$ This is an isomorphism since it maps a basis onto a basis.

Why is $$f\left(\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)F(e_1)\otimes ...\otimes F(e_n)\right)=\det F$$ for $F\in\text{GL}(V)$?

Comment: It depends on how you define the determinant... Probably the most conceptual way to do this is to **define** the determinant like that and derive the usual formulae from there.

Comment: Well, I know that formula of a $n\times n$-matrix which looks quite similar, but the determinant of an endomorphism is defined as the determinant of its matrix. Why is this the same? :)

Comment: It might be worthwhile to work this out explicitly for a $2\times2$ matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the determinant is to measure how a linear map "changes the volume".

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and fix a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. The $n$-th exterior product $\Lambda^nV$ is $1$-dimensional and carries the canonical basis given by the element
$$v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n\ .$$
Notice that it represents an ideal element of "volume $1$" (namely, the unit cube in $V$ with respect to the notion of volume induced by fixing the basis). A linear map
$$A:V\longrightarrow V$$
canonically induces a linear map
$$\Lambda^nA:\Lambda^nV\longrightarrow\Lambda^nV$$
by
$$\Lambda^nA(v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n) = Av_1\wedge\cdots\wedge Av_n\in\Lambda^nV\ .$$
Since $\Lambda^nV$ is $1$-dimensional, we **define** the determinant as the unique number $\det(A)$ such that
$$\Lambda^nA(v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n) = \det(A)v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n\ .$$
It is a good exercise (which I leave to you) to check that if you take $V=\mathbb{C}^n$ and $A$ a matrix, then you recover the usual formulae.

---

An additional remark. An even better ($=$ more conceptual) way to approach the definition of determinant is by fixing a volume form on $V$ instead of a basis, i.e. an element
$$\rho\in\Lambda^nV^*$$
and going from there. When $V$ is finite dimensional, fixing a basis gives us an isomorphism $V\cong V^*$ (via the inner product $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$) and an induced isomorphism $\Lambda^nV^*\cong\Lambda^nV$. In this setting, of course, $\rho$ corresponds to $v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n$.